# How to do a Mail Merge in C# using Interop.Word?

Tags: c#, printing, interop, ms-word, placeholder

I have a template in Word that would be used to print out invoices.

Now, I would like to know how to create a Word Document programmatically and copy the template content into the new document so that I still have a clean template, then replace placeholders that I have typed by using Mail.Merge. I found similar Mail.Merge questions but most require Spire components and I am not interested since it needs to be paid for. I am only a student. Others though, actually doesn't help that much.

The problems I am facing now are as follows:

1. Create a Word document
2. Copy template content into new document
3. How to add placeholder names into `MailMerge` since I'm very confused about this.
4. Do `MailMerge`

Here is the current code that I have concocted, this is actually the first time I have used Interops

```
Document document = new Document();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
document = wordApp.Documents.Open(fileName);
string[] fieldNames = {"date_issued", "month_covered", "tuition", "lunchfee", "discount", "in_no", "student_no", "student_name", "amount_due", "amount_paid", "balance", "penalty", "status"};
string[] data = new string[25];
Range range;
document.MailMerge.Fields.Add(range, fieldNames[0]);
document.MailMerge.Execute();
```

I'm really confused on this part

```
document.MailMerge.Fields.Add(range, fieldNames[0]);
```

and I don't know what `range` is for

Comment: This is the fileName variable   string fileName = @"C:\IMAGES\template.doc";

Comment: See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301659?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your template is an actual template and not a plain Word Document (with the extension .dotx or .dot, and not .docx/.doc), you don't need to copy anything. Just create a new document based on the template:

```
var doc = wordApp.Documents.Add("put template path here");
```

This will have the contents of your template. If you have used the Word UI to setup a mailmerge in the template (including the location of the data for the merge), that will also be carried over into the new document.

Then you can execute the mailmerge from C#:

```
doc.MailMerge.Execute();
```

Comment: I actually don't know what data source you are talking about. How do I add the data programmatically through c#? and how do I create an actual template in Word?

Comment: I just clarified this in the answer.

Comment: What if you want to use some data that you've pieced together into a DataTable in memory as the source for the merge?

Comment: I don't think Word natively supports using a DataTable as a merge source. You'd have to output it first to some data source that Word can use: CSV, Excel, Access etc. Alternatively, you could iterate through the document programmatically, and replace each merge field with the corresponding value from the DataTable.